# Não consigo capturar erro usando Try-Catch no Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iphone

Estou fazendo um *app*, o qual está me dando um certo erro em algum momento, porém só está ocorrendo em certos dispositivos. Estou tentando capturar este erro com o `do/catch`, porém não estou conseguindo capturá-lo.

O código está da seguinte maneira:

```
do {
    try self.minhaFuncao()
} catch let error1 as NSError {
    self.enviarEmailComErro(error1.description)
}
```

Eu sei que o erro está localizado no `minhaFuncao()`, código:

```
func initApp() throws {
    //Faço várias coisas aqui
}
```

Como faço para capturar estes erros que podem ocorrer dentro deste método?

Comment: a sintaxe está correta, teria que ver como você lança a exception dentro do método initApp

Comment: qual é a exceção? Lembrando que o try-catch do Swift somente captura exceções de Swift, se sua exceção for de Obj-c continuará dando erro.

Comment: Poste o que o método `initApp()` faz, fica difícil imaginar do nada onde o erro pode estar.

Answer (score 1):

Veja bem, `try catch` não captura somente ponteiros de `NSError`, eles servem para capturar **exceptions** que estejam de acordo com o protocolo `ErrorType`.

Como que você vai saber quando é possível capturar uma exception? Qual o tipo de exception? E como você pode também usar esse recurso para arremessar erros a partir do seu código?

No Swift 2, você vai ter duas situações:

### 1. Metodos do Objective-C que marcam erros em sua execução

Em Objective-C, alguns métodos recebem como parâmetro, um ponteiro para um erro, esse ponteiro serve para sinalizar o desenvolvedor que, se caso algo de errado, você precisa fazer algo sobre a falha.

Um exemplo:

```
NSError *error;

NSString *someString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, &error];

// Se o ponteiro definido no ultimo parâmetro não for nil, significa que algo deu errado.
if ( error ) {
  // caso algo de errado, faça algo aqui.
}
```

Ok, agora que deve ter ficado claro como fazer isso em Objective-C, vamos ver como fazer a mesma coisa em Swift.

A primeira coisa a se ter em mente é que, a partir do Swift 2, todos os métodos em Objective-C que recebem um ponteiro de NSError, não recebem um ponteiro em Swift, eles arremessam uma exceção e isso é visível logo na assinatura do método:

`convenience init(contentsOfURL url: NSURL, encoding enc: UInt) throws`

Perceba o `throws` no final da assinatura do mesmo método que mostrei em Objective-C.

Ok sabendo disso, você **DEVE** colocar qualquer execução desse (ou de qualquer método marcado com throw), dentro de um bloco de manipulação de exceção `try catch`. Mas neste caso, você não vai receber uma exceção, e sim um `NSError`, como descrito na documentação:

> In Swift, this method returns a nonoptional result and is marked with the throws keyword to indicate that it throws an error in cases of failure.

Para capturar esses possíveis erros, você usa a seguinte implementação em Swift:

```
do {
  let str = try NSString(contentsOfURL: url, enconding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
catch let error as NSError {
  // caso algo de errado, faça algo aqui
}
```

### 2. Métodos que podem arremessar uma exceção

Vamos supor, que você quer que implementar uma função hipotética que, faça a conversão de strings em números ok?

```
func convertToInt (string: String) -> Int {
  return Int(string)!
}
```

Usar esse método, seria simples assim:

```
let str = "12345"
let int = convertToInt(str) // int = 1234 literal
```

Ok parece que funciona, mas e se por acaso, alguém passar uma string diferente?

```
let str = "1234a"
let int convertToInt(str) // Error
```

Este é o tipo de método que com certeza pode dar errado, então para que o programa não pare de executar e você possa sinalizar quem está usando a fim de corrigir o problema, você pode usar um protocolo `ErrorType` para arremessar erros customizados e dar a dica de como corrigi-lo.

Vamos fazer um `ErrorType` bem simples para este caso:

enum StringToIntError: ErrorType {
  case NotANumber
}

Este enumerador, serve para sinalizar um tipo de erro. Vamos agora mudar o método `convertToInt`, para que ele possa arremessar este erro, caso o retorno "não seja um número".

```
func convertToInt (string: String) throws -> Int {
  let i: Int? = Int(string);

  guard (i != nil) else { throw StringToIntError.NotANumber }

  return i!
}
```

Então agora, toda vez que `i` **opcionalmente** for nil, o método vai arremessar o erro `StringToIntError.NotANUmber`.

Agora podemos usar o método `convertToInt` de forma mais segura, desta maneira:

```
do {
  let int2 = try convertToInt(str2)
  print( int2 )
}
catch StringToIntError.NotANumber {
  print( "Não é um número" )
}
```

Bom, sei que a explicação ficou um pouco longa, mas isso é um resumo de como trabalhar com tratamentos de erro no Swift.

Espero que isso possa te ajudar a entender seu problema e corrigi-lo.

Have a nice code.